# ssis package ado destination Data Conversion warning

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

i'm working on ssis package and i'm taking values from .xml file to ado .net destination

but when i enter values iinto table getting following error :

> potential data loss may occur due to inserting data from input column "Copy of swaps_Id" with data type "DT_I8" to external column "swaps_id" with data type "DT_I4". If this is intended, an alternative way to do conversion is using a Data Conversion component before ADO NET destination component

I have used `Data conversion transformation editor` then also getting above error

what should be corrected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning means that data in `Copy of swaps_Id` is 64bit integer and you trying to insert it into 32bit integer column in destination table. What should you do depends on your data.

1. If you are sure that data in your column is in 32bit signed integer range (-2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)) you can leave it as is (data truncation will never occur, bur warning will stay) or do data conversion or change `Copy of swaps_Id` column data type
2. If not, you should change column data type in your destination data table to 64bit integer (`bigint` in Sql Server)

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that your source data type is Larger than what your destination can handle. On the Data Conversion Transformation, you may want to convert the column to DT_I8 datatype in order for that warning to disappear.